# How to add footprint to a schematic symbol from any PCB library in Altium

Tags: altium

I created a PCB schematic symbol and a PCB footprint, both .SchLib and .PcbLib added to my projects and in "Installed libraries".
When I go to the schematic symbol, click "Add footprint" -> Browse, in the "Libraries" drop down (see image) only one PcbLib appears although I have several. If I go to my project tree and double click another PcbLib and come back, then it will appear on the list, but will again be the only item there.

So my question is, how does Altium choose which libraries appear in this list? Why do they appear only one by one in my case, am I doing something wrong or is this a known bug?

Thanks

[image: Add PCB foot print window]

Comment: Did  you click on the three dots to the right of the chevron?

Comment: What libraries are added to your project?